# How to calculate solstices and equinoxes?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I know the orbit of my fictional planet, and I can set its rotation rate with precision. I know that, in our real world, the equinoxes and solstices are measured, not calculated, but I want to know if there is a way to calculate at least an approximation of when they would happen, given for example a point in the orbit (in degrees) and the planet's rotation rate or any other relevant data point (its orbit's semi major axis, for example).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: I know I could hand-wave it, divide the length of the year in 4, and set four equidistant dates for them to be equinoxes and solstices, but I want to know if there is a way to know the exact date.

EDIT 2: I also know that the orientation of the planet's axial tilt varies with time (I established a cycle of 20000 earth years). But the axial tilt doesn't change too much in a given year, that's why the equinoxes and solstices fall in approximately the same dates.

Answer (score 4):

[Solstices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solstice) and [equinoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox) are moments:

> A solstice is an event that occurs when the Sun appears to reach its most northerly or southerly excursion relative to the celestial equator on the celestial sphere.

> An equinox is the instant of time when the plane of Earth's equator passes through the geometric center of the Sun's disk.

For the actual calculation you would need tables with the equation of time and the anomalies of the Sun, an example of actual calculation is given [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Syntaxis/Almagest/node36.html)

> We can also use Tables 32 and 33 to calculate the dates of the equinoxes and solstices, and, hence, the lengths of the seasons, in a given year. The vernal equinox (i.e., the point on the sun's apparent orbit at which it passes through the celestial equator from south to north) corresponds to $\lambda = 0^\circ$, the summer solstice (i.e., the point at which the sun is furthest north of the celestial equator) to $\lambda = 90^\circ$, the autumnal equinox (i.e., the point at which the sun passes through the celestial equator from north to south) to $\lambda = 180^\circ$, and the winter solstice (i.e., the point at which the sun is furthest south of the celestial equator) to $\lambda = 270^\circ$.
>
> Consider the year 2000 CE. For the case of the vernal equinox, we can first estimate the time at which this event takes place by approximating the solar longitude as the mean solar longitude: i.e.,
>
> $\lambda\simeq \bar{\lambda} = \bar{\lambda}_0 + n\,(t-t_0) = 280.458 + 0.98564735\,(t-t_0) $
>
> [...] an estimate for the date of the vernal equinox is
>
> $ t = t_0 + 81 -2.177/0.98564735 \simeq t_0 + 78.8\,{\rm JD}, $
>
> which corresponds to 7:00 UT on March 20

Comment: Nice answer. In first definition this "celestial equator on the celestial sphere" kills the whole simplicity of first definition, second definition is perfect in that sense.

Answer (score 3):

Its all down to the relative angle of the planet's rotation axis, and its orbit.

Literally, the solstices appear when the planet's axis angle points as close as it gets at/away from its sun, and the equinoxes occur when the axis is at its maximum angle from the sun (thus pointing as close to orbit track as it can get)

Comment: That's what I thought. Because I live far away from the equator, the sun isn't directly above me at our summer solstice here, so I can't quite notice when the solstice is.

Comment: Like the answer for it's practical simplicity, but formulating in that way seems incorrect? "axis is at its _maximum angle from the sun_",  this equaterial definition from L.Dutch answer on pair with simplicity, so as it is correct one "An equinox .. plane of Earth's equator passes through the geometric center of the Sun's disk." Have difficulty to write axial definiton of the same. But maybe I didn't understood your sentence, idk

Comment: @MolbOrg yeah. Not happy with my phrasing myself. I know what I want to say, but it requires an interactive 3-d gizmo to show the relative angles of rotation axis and orbital plane, which just looks wrong with 2-d images and worse than wrong with short words.

Comment: Yep, same here, simpliest I just did come by is, there is a plane perpendicular to orbit,  which crosses centers of sun and earth, and then solstices is when the axis lays in the plane(angle between the plane and axis is 0), and equinoxes when it has max angle to the plane, which btw is tilt angle of the planet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and can tell solstice and equinox are both calculated all the time. Because of Earth's tilt not really changing in oriantation it is almost as simple as (but not really, because real orbits are elliptical) dividing the orbital period in four. For a matter of fact, the Gregorian calendar effectively fixes the equinoxes and solstices to specific dates.
Read more: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solstice#:~:text=A%20solstice%20is%20an%20event,June%2021%20and%20December%2021](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solstice#:%7E:text=A%20solstice%20is%20an%20event,June%2021%20and%20December%2021).
http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Syntaxis/Almagest/node36.html

Comment: I have read the article on wikipedia already, but I didn't get any new information, except that the answer is "measured". And about Earth's axis, it does change in orientation (and also the tilt changes, see the article on Nutation) but very slowly (I read that it does a complete cycle in 26,000 years)

Answer (score 0):

Any of the astrophysicists on this site could do a better job than I, but here goes.

**1. The trivial condition**

- Axial tilt = 0°
- Non-tidally locked
- Planetary axis is 90° off the orbital plane.
- Orbit is perfectly circular

There are no solstices, no equinoxes, and no seasons. Measuring the orbit in polar coordinates, there are no local minima or maxima. The distance from the sun never changes.

**2. Elongate the orbit, but leave it centered on the sun**

Again, using polar coordinates, we now have two local minima and two local maxima. The minima are equal to one another and the maxima are equal to one another. In this circumstance, we have no equinoxes. We do have two solstices: one winter, one summer, and they happen *twice* each year. Remember that the planetary axial tilt is still 0°.

Now, philosophically there are four equinoxes. That's because an equinox is, simplistically, the point along the orbit when the distance between the sun and the planet is (maxima - minima)/2 + minima. But there's something magic about the equinoxes we experience on Earth, and it doesn't happen when the axial tilt is 0°.

**3. Offset the elliptical orbit such that the sun is no longer at the center of the orbit**

It's worth noting that Earth's orbit is only slightly elliptical and only slightly off-center (and I might be wrong about that). But it doesn't take much — especially with an axial tilt > 0°. But, one step at a time.

With the sun no longer at (0,0) (yeah, yeah, yeah... cartesian coordinates in a polar coordinate conversation. Sue me.) we now have one local minima, one local maxima, and the "half-way" point between the two. That half-way point can be defined a second way: it's the point on either side of the orbit between the minima and maxima where the first derivative is zero (doing this requires defining the first derivative at the minima and maxima as infinity... you get my point).

Now we have two solstices and two equinoxes. One winter, one summer, a spring and a fall.

But, like I said, Earth's orbit is actually pretty close to circular and has little to no offset from the star. So, what causes all those pesky seasons?  Yup, axial tilt.

**4. Perfectly circular orbit, axial tilt > 0°**

When you ignore the orbit by making it perfectly circular, the axial tilt gives you the equinoxes and solstices. Local minima and maxima exist for a hemisphere (and are duplicated but in reverse for the other hemisphere). So, for example, Europe has a point in the orbit when it is closest to the sun (summer), another when it's furthest from the sun (winter), and those two half-way points where, when the rotation brings it to face the sun, it's half-way between the minima and maxima. Again (and without the complication of orbit), winter, summer, spring, fall.

But here's where we can point out the magical nature of an axial-tilt equinox — and we'll use the two tropics (the tropic of cancer and the tropic of capricorn) to explain it. It's that point (and there's two of them) along the orbit where the distance from the two tropics to the sun is equal. At all other points along the orbit, the two tropics are different distances from the sun. When the axial tilt is 0°, the distance from the two tropics to the sun is *always* equal. With a tilt, it only happens twice each year.

And that's a third way to define an equinox and the one that meets the definition of an equinox that we humans use on Earth: the date (twice each year) when the sun crosses the celestial equator and the day and night are of approximately equal length.

**Conclusion: Calculating the solstices and equinoxes**

Hopefully what you've realized is that calculating the solstices is fairly straight forward — but calculating the equinoxes is not, because it depends on your definition of an equinox and how that definition relates to the orbit and axial tilt.

Unfortunately, I don't have a universal formula. I'm sure someone has created one — but I think it's just as fast to work the four points out empirically.

Comment: "closest to the sun (summer), another when it's furthest from the sun (winter)," - closest eh?, u mean less than 12k km makes such a huge difference, eh, lol. Hated that explanation at school, just didn't knew better what's wrong with it at that time. Seems cartesian coordinates did bite u after all, lol

Comment: You can't elongate the orbit and leave it centered at the sun. Newton's laws of gravity don't work that way ... if the orbit is elliptical, the sun is at one of the foci of the ellipse.

Comment: Yes, orbits are elliptical with the star in one of the foci, but the planets don't orbit the star itself, but the center of mass, which, if I understand correctly, lies between the planet and the star, so the center of the ellipse.

Comment: @ZenielDanaku, the center of mass of the whole solar system is well within the Sun, and has nothing to do with the center of the ellipse

Comment: If I understand correctly, while it is within the Sun, it doens't coincide with the Sun's center. That's what I was trying to say.